# How to update the heading Levels for Table Of Contents in Word Online?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, table-of-contents

I am able to modify table of content using Desktop Word application installed locally. Id don't see the same option in Word online (OneDrive). Is there a way this can be done using Word online?

Comment: I don't thinik it's possible using the Word Online user interface. To do it *without* a desktop version of Word, you would have to be able to change the field code for the { TOC } field (and be sure that the Online version will always honour the new options). IN principle you could edit the document's code using a text editor, but only if you could save in a plain text type format such as .xml. But you can't do that from the Online version.

Comment: So to do that manual edit you would have to save as .docx, find some way to unzip that or extract the document.xml, edit that in a text editor, put the updated .xml back into the zipped .docx. Otherwise, if you can find or write, then deploy, an Office-JS addin that is capable of finding the ToC field code and modifying it, that might work. *Perhaps* if you need to do this a lot and are syncing your Online documents with your local machine, you could write some VBA to run in your local machine that knows how to access the local copies of the files. None of those are particularly easy IMO.

Comment: Word online is a different program. It does not have this feature.